# Reading from file into linked list in C

Tags: c, list, memory, dynamic

I have to read from a text file which has a format :

```
TRMMMYQ128F932D901-SEP-SOQMMHC12AB0180CB8<SEP>Faster Pussy cat-SEP-Silent Night
```

This is my code for writing into linked list and then printing it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

typedef struct song {
char *id;
char *songId;
char *artist;
char *title;
struct song *nextSong;
} song;

char *strdup(const char *c)
{
char *dup = malloc(strlen(c) + 1);

if (dup != NULL)
    strcpy(dup, c);

return dup;
}

int main()
{
FILE *fp;
char line[400];
char *item;

song *root = NULL;
song *current = NULL;

int i = 0;

fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\DelicAnte\\Desktop\\unique_tracks.txt", "r");

if (!fp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot be opened");
}
printf("starting");
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {

    if (root == NULL) {

        root = malloc(sizeof(song));
        /*root->id = strtok(line, "<SEP>");
        root->songId = strtok(NULL, "<SEP>");
        root->artist = strtok(NULL, "<SEP>");
        root->title = strtok(NULL, "<SEP>");*/

        item = strtok(line, "<SEP>");
        root->id = strdup(item);

        item = strtok(NULL, "<SEP>");
        root->songId = strdup(item);

        item = strtok(NULL, "<SEP>");
        root->artist = strdup(item);

        item = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        root->title = strdup(item);

        root->nextSong = NULL;

    }
    else {

        current = root;
        if (current != NULL) {
            while (current->nextSong != NULL) {
                current = current->nextSong;
            }
        }
        /*current = malloc(sizeof(song));
        current->id = strtok(line, "<SEP>");
        current->songId = strtok(NULL, "<SEP>");
        current->artist = strtok(NULL, "<SEP>");
        current->title = strtok(NULL, "<SEP>");*/


        current->nextSong = malloc(sizeof(song));
        current = current->nextSong;

        item = strtok(line, "<SEP>");
        current->id = strdup(item);
        //current->id = malloc(strlen(item) + 1);
        //strcpy(current->id, item);

        item = strtok(NULL, "<SEP>");
        current->songId = strdup(item);
        //current->songId = malloc(strlen(item) + 1);
        //strcpy(current->songId, item);

        item = strtok(NULL, "<SEP>");
        current->artist = strdup(item);
        //current->artist = malloc(strlen(item) + 1);
        //strcpy(current->artist, item);

        item = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        current->title = strdup(item);
        //current->title = malloc(strlen(item) + 1);
        //strcpy(current->title, item);

        current->nextSong = NULL;

        printf("%d\n", i);
        i++;

    }

}

fclose(fp);

current = root;

if (current != NULL) {
    while (current->nextSong != NULL) {
        printf("%s %s\n", current->artist, current->title);
        current = current->nextSong;
    }
    printf("%s %s %s %s\n", current->id, current->songId, current->artist, current->title);
}
else {
    printf("NULA JE");
}


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

But I get really wierd output of incomplete strings.

Comment: Incomplete strings could result from a bug in the input-parsing code as well. So I advise you to decouple that from the linked list implementation first: Write a test program which does not create a linked list but reads in the entries from the file and simply outputs them. Using this program, you can verify first that your io code is correct. If the problem then persists, you are certain it has something to do with your linked list implementation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok(line, "<SEP>");` will look for character delimiters which include `<`, `S`, `E`, `P`, `>`

Use `strstr` if you need to search for `"<SEP>"` string

Otherwise change the delimiter to `;` and define the data as follows:

```
TRMMMYQ128F932D901;SOQMMHC12AB0180CB8;Faster Pussy cat;Silent Night
```

Your linked list is repeating the same code. You can simplify as follows and add error handling:

```
char *sep = ";";
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) 
{
    current = malloc(sizeof(song));
    current->nextSong = NULL;

    item = strtok(line, sep);
    if(!item) break;
    current->id = strdup(item);
    item = strtok(NULL, sep);
    if(!item) break;
    current->songId = strdup(item);
    item = strtok(NULL, sep);
    if(!item) break;
    current->artist = strdup(item);
    item = strtok(NULL, sep);
    if(!item) break;
    current->title = strdup(item);

    if(root)
        current->nextSong = root;
    root = current;
}
fclose(fp);
```

In addition, when printing the code walk through the list and print every valid element as follows:

```
if(root) 
{
    current = root;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s %s %s %s\n", 
          current->id, current->songId, current->artist, current->title);
        current = current->nextSong;
    }
}
```

This code does not free any of the memory allocated. You can do that for the next step.